# Difference between backward martingales and martingales.

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales

I can't see a difference between a martingale and a backward martingale except for the index. What is the difference besides this? If we consider the reverse filtration then it is a martingale. In other words by going upwards.

Answer (score 0):

The index set $\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$ of a (discrete time) martingale has a first element but is "infinite to the right".  The index set $\{\ldots,-2,-1,0\}$ of a (discrete time) backward martingale has a last element but is "infinite to the left".  In the latter case, call the martingale $(Y_n)$; you then have $Y_n =\Bbb E[Y_0\mid\mathcal F_n]$ for each $n<0$. In particular, the sequence $(Y_n)$ is *uniformly integrable*, and this is the key difference between the two notions.

Comment: what if we put $\mathcal{F}_{0}=\{\Omega,\emptyset\}$ and $\lim Y_{n}=X_{0}$ and $Y_{0}=X_{\infty}$ is it only integrability that differs then?